# Match entire line containing certain text, and add a string after newline

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string like so:

```
*question: What percentage is the correct answer? 
    33%
    15%
    2%
    25%
```

I need to add, after the question line, a `shuffle` command:

```
*question: What percentage is the correct answer? 
    *shuffle
    33%
    15%
    2%
    25%
```

What is the best way for going about doing so?  I'm fine using any Notepad editor or Python.

I thought I could use the following regex to capture everything on the first line: `^(\*question).*`, but I'm not sure how to add the `*shuffle` syntax directly after the newline.

Comment: Is it small file?

Comment: [`^(\*question.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/G3awGM/2/) is this what you're trying ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re

data = """
*question: What percentage is the correct answer? 
    33%
    15%
    2%
    25%
"""

rx = re.compile(r'(\*question.+)', re.M)

data = rx.sub(r'\1\n    *shuffle', data)
print(data)
```

Which yields

```
*question: What percentage is the correct answer? 
    *shuffle
    33%
    15%
    2%
    25%
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^(\*question.*)
```

[image]

and replace by

```
\1\n\t*shffule
```

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/G3awGM/3/)

Comment: Thanks!  That's a neat visualizer. How did you generate that?

Comment: @Parseltongue you can use this tool. [`jex.im/regulex`](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%5C*question.*))